# Android Resize MapView after Visibility change

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've got an activity with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to be able to hide/show the seperate LinearLayout with id 'view' and then let the MapView resize according to the space left. When I try this the seperate LinearLayout is never shown. I'm not sure what is going on! Is the LinearLayout forever hidden? is it behind the Mapview?

```
private void showMessage() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);
    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void hideMessage() {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);
    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I also tried calling the main LinearLayout's `requestLayout()` method, no results..

Comment: Oddly it seems to work if I move the LinearLayout with id 'view' above the MapView. Below the MapView doesn't seem to work this way? Is this a bug? Can people verify this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be resolved by changing the order of initialization in the XML layout file, and it probably won't occur in future Android versions.